# Elasticbeanstalk version errors when deploying new application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Platform : Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.7

1. I've set up my .elasticbeanstlk config.yml by doing `eb init`
2. I've made a new EB environment, by doing `eb create`
3. I've deployed my EB application by doing `eb deploy`

But now I'm facing a problem when deploying a new application to my elasticbeanstalk environment. Before I deployed my application by ElasticBeanstalk... and I'm trying to update my application to the new version.

**First try**

[When I upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny6Sb.png), the [deploy fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tCEi.png):

> During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate version.

**Second try**

- `brew install awsebcli`
- `eb init` -> `eb deploy`

Then `eb deploy` fails:

[image: AWS Access Denied error notice]

**Third try**

I changed my S3 policy, from

```json
"Sid": "something",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
},
"Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
"Resource": "something"
```

to

```json
"Sid": "something",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
},
"Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
"Resource": "something"
```

That caused [another error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76crW.png):

> Service:Amazon S3, Message:Access Denied

Plus, whenever I deploy the way I did the first time, my S3 policy automatically is changed again to "S3 delete deny…."

My questions are ...

1. How can I configure S3 policy to make `eb deploy` successful?
2. What is the difference between uploading `.zip` applications via direct upload (through AWS homepage) and via the command-line interface (aws eb cli)?

---

Comment: Did you check any EB logs for errors?

Comment: yes! I checked eb logs   -cfn-init.log,cfn-cmd-init.log, eb-engine.log   I found my source code uploaded at /var/app/staging area but no proceed to var/app/current